# sed: Replace words in pattern with variables across 1 or more lines

Tags: bash, sed

I'm writing a bash script that will scan a list of PHP files to look for a specific "class X extends Y" string and replace Y with another string that I have chosen (Z).

- X is unknown to me, it will be different for each file (I don't need
  to know what it is, only that it exists)
- Y is known, and must match in order for the substitution to take place.
- Z is also known (obviously)

So far I've managed to come up with a sed line that works if the entire class X extends Y pattern is on one line, but I can't seem to get it to work where, for example, there is a newline after X, with "extends" following on the next line (in some cases prefaced with a tab/whitespace).  I guess it could be possible for "class", X, "extends" and Y to be on 4 separate lines and still be valid PHP?  I dunno..

My sed line so far is as follows (this is inside of a loop):

```
sed -i -E "s/class (\w+) extends $OLDMODEL/\/\/ Modified by `basename "$0"` - `date` - Original model: $OLDMODEL\n\tclass \1 extends $NEWMODEL/" $FILELOC
```

In the above line $OLDMODEL is Y, $NEWMODEL is Z, and $FILELOC is the absolute path to the file to be changed.  When matched, the command inserts a comment above the changed line that records the script name, the date/time the change was made, and the substituted class.

Most of the tutorials I've seen online that deal with multi-line pattern matching seem to use **sed -e** rather than **-E**, which is causing me issues with variable substitution and other things that are only working with extended regexp.

X, Y and Z are alphabetic strings with underscores in, e.g. Some_Model_Class_Thing

Would appreciate any help anyone can give me.  Thanks in advance :)

I realise I could probably use perl or python, but if it's possible in sed I'd like to be able to get it working, particularly as one-line substitutions are working fine.

**Sample input:**

```
 1. class FooModule_Sales_Model_Quote extends BarModule_Some_Other_Class
 2. class FooModule_Sales_Model_Quote
            extends BarModule_Some_Other_Class
```

**Sample output:**

```
 1. class FooModule_Sales_Model_Quote extends New_Module_Better_Class
 2. class FooModule_Sales_Model_Quote extends New_Module_Better_Class
```

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: `\w` looks kind of strange here. I don't know much about php, but underscores are allowed in php names too. [php docs](https://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.phpx) (php, really `\xff` is allowed in function name...). To handle newlines, if you use GNU sed, just use `-z` (remember to use `g` global flag). Is `1.` and `2.` part of input/output?

Comment: According to https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/regexp-extensions.html:
\w - Matches any “word” character. A “word” character is any letter or digit or the underscore character.

In this particular instance it the names will only ever be alphabetic with underscores.

Comment: Honestly, I'd just use Perl. `perl -i -pE 's/.../.../'` emulates sed, and then you can just add `-0777` to make it process the whole file as one string.

Comment: `-e` is totally unrelated to `-E` (you can use one or the other or both) and neither have anything to do with `variable substitution`. wrt `this is inside of a loop` - what is the loop for?

Comment: The loop is because I have an array of PHP files to change, so I use the sed command on each file in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed with `-z` option you could:

```
sed -z 's@class[[:space:]]\+'"$X"'[[:space:]]\+extends[[:space:]]\+'"$Y"'\([[:space:]{]\)@class '"$X"' extends '"$Z"'\1@g'
```

Tested on [repl](https://repl.it/repls/SourBlandEvents):

```
cat <<EOF >input
1. class FooModule_Sales_Model_Quote extends BarModule_Some_Other_Class
2. class FooModule_Sales_Model_Quote
            extends BarModule_Some_Other_Class

EOF

X=FooModule_Sales_Model_Quote
Y=BarModule_Some_Other_Class
Z=New_Module_Better_Class

<input sed -z 's@'\
'class[[:space:]]\+'"$X"'[[:space:]]\+extends[[:space:]]\+'"$Y"'\([[:space:]{]\)@'\
'class '"$X"' extends '"$Z"'\1@g'
```

will output:

```
1. class FooModule_Sales_Model_Quote extends New_Module_Better_Class
2. class FooModule_Sales_Model_Quote extends New_Module_Better_Class
```

Note that you can preserve the newlines in input, just `\([[:space:]]\+\)` save them in a backreference and reference in the substituted string.

I also added the `\([[:space:]{]\)` need for a whitespace or `{` behind `extends $Y` class name. There is a possibility that regex will match part of the class, ex. you may want to substitute `BarModule_Some` for something and `BarModule_Some_Other_Class` for something different. So that `sed` doesn't match both in one regex, you need to match the next character after the class name.

Without gnu sed, you could susbtitute newlines for some unreadable character  `tr '\n' $'\01'`, run sed and then revert back `tr $'\01' '\n'`.

Comment: Thanks @kamil-cuk.  This is close I think, except that I don't know what $X is, so it won't be in a variable.  I just need the $X portion identified and duplicated in the substituted string, if that makes sense.

I just need to search for $Y and replace with $Z.  The $X part will stay the same, so I presume I could use something like [:alpha:], or the equivalent of ^[a-zA-Z_\x80-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x80-\xff]*$ - per [this page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)

Comment: Answering my own comment, but I came up with this which seems to work:

`sed -i -z 's@class[[:space:]]\([A-Za-z_]\{1,\}\)[[:space:]]\+extends[[:space:]]\+'"$Y"'\([[:space:]{]\)@class \1 extends '"$Z"'\2@g' $FILELOC`

Won't handle all valid PHP class names, but will suffice for my needs as I haven't come across any that don't fit [a-zA-Z_] in this instance.

Comment: I've accepted your answer as it got me 95% of the way there.  Thanks very much for taking the time to reply.